# single activity with multiple xml file

Tags: java, android

how to create single activity and multiple xml file for that activity? 
button click from main activity should should display different button in next activity(which has multiple xml file) when i click different button.
I created different xml file but how to link that with java?

Comment: is it single activity?

Comment: This doesn't sound like you should be using a single activity.  It sounds like you should be using multiple activities or fragments.

Comment: you must be asking about fragments?

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the previous comments that your approach doesn't sound right and that you're probably wanting multiple activities and/or fragments. But it **is** possible to display the contents of more than one XML file at the same time. You can do that via the [addContentView()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#addContentView(android.view.View,%20android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams)) method. Here's a small method that will display a second simultaneous view:

```
private void addSecondView() {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    FrameLayout layout = (FrameLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_two, null);

    FrameLayout.LayoutParams fllp = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    addContentView(layout, fllp);
}
```